# Cut function in R

Tags: r

My dataset class has "**time**" feature. This feature belongs to character class.
I try to show the frequency of pick up per different time slot.For this reason, I used "cut" function as below:

```
FreqPickupTime <- cut(dt$time, breaks = "hour")
```

But, I occur with the below error.

> Error in cut.default(dt$time, breaks = "hour") :'x' must be numeric.

is there any solution to use this cut function for character features.

Comment: `cut()` won't work on character values. Are you string dates in the column? Then you'll need to convert to a proper date time value. See `?strptime`. The `cut()` function has special properties for date time (POSIXt) values. It would be better if you included a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input data so we know exactly what your data looks like.

Answer (score 2):

As MrFlick says, `cut()` won't cut it for characters.

Say `df$time` looks something like: `16:42, 12:32, 03:20...`

For example:

```
time <- paste0(round(runif(1000, 0, 23), digits = 0), ':', round(runif(1000, 1, 59), digits = 0))
```

You could simply do:

```
table(substr(time, 1, regexpr(':', time)-1))
```

Comment: thanks for the sample but it does not work on my data set. My data is like "00:28:14". I want to use subset data based on time slot 00:00- 6:00, and 6:00- 12:00 , and 12:00 - 5:00 and ...

Comment: All right, did you remember to change the variable name in the `table()` call to `table(substr(df$time, 1, regexpr(':', df$time)-1))'`? Maybe, try to post what `typeof(df$time)`returns here? The thing is, this code should work even if your data is formated the way you say.

Comment: use `df$time <- as.POSIXct(df$time)` and then `cut` will work.